# Searching for a fast variant to find indices of words in a huge matrix (30000000 elements)

Tags: r

```
stimword.idx <- match(keyword, matrix)
```

Duration: 70 sec

Searching for a fast variant to find indices of words in a huge matrix (30000000 elements). Currently I'm using the `match()` function. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Maybe `fmatch` from library `fastmatch`